# unable to find "istio-egress" service with minikube installation

Tags: istio

I followed the instruction provided on "https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start.html" that says "Ensure the following Kubernetes services are deployed: istio-pilot, istio-mixer, istio-ingress, istio-egress"

However, when I do "kubectl get svc --all-namespaces", only the following services show up:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                            AGE
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                                                            39m
istio-system   istio-ca-ilb           LoadBalancer   10.98.239.183    <pending>     8060:31894/TCP                                                     7m
istio-system   istio-ingress          LoadBalancer   10.103.124.167   <pending>     80:30341/TCP,443:30145/TCP                                         24m
istio-system   istio-mixer            ClusterIP      10.104.162.202   <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9102/TCP,9125/UDP,42422/TCP   24m
istio-system   istio-pilot            ClusterIP      10.106.111.86    <none>        15003/TCP,443/TCP                                                  24m
istio-system   istio-pilot-ilb        LoadBalancer   10.106.250.124   <pending>     8080:32752/TCP                                                     7m
istio-system   mixer-ilb              LoadBalancer   10.103.131.44    <pending>     9091:30549/TCP                                                     7m
kube-system    dns-ilb                LoadBalancer   10.98.70.111     <pending>     53:30347/UDP                                                       7m
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                                                      38m
kube-system    kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort       10.110.39.52     <none>        80:30000/TCP                                                       38m
```

Then I search the keyword "istio-egress" in "install/kubernetes/istio.yaml" and unable to find any... Is this something new to v0.3.0 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. It seems like the document issue, since istio-egress was removed (see https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/1202).

So, don't worry for now. Filed https://github.com/istio/istio.github.io/issues/792